# Using pfSense on proxmox as an Internet router for my LAN

Tags: networking, routing, firewall, pfsense, proxmox

I have 2 networks, one is **192.168.0.0/24** and the other is **192.168.1.0/24**.
The first network has access to the Internet and the Internet gateway is **192.168.0.1**(my dsl router IP).
The second one has not access to Internet.
Now I want to use pfSense as a router/dhcp so devices on the network **192.168.1.0/24** can access to the Internet.

Settings I did on pfSense (Setting IP for Interfaces):

```
WAN:
Static:
    IP:192.168.0.55/24
    GATEWAY:192.168.0.1
    Should be default gateway? Yes.
    IP V6? No
    DHCP Server on WAN? No.
    Revert Web Panel To HTTP? Yes.
Lan:    
Static:
    IP:192.168.1.1/24
    I choosed Enter between these 2:
        For a WAN enter a new lan upstream gateway ipv4 address.
        For a lan press enter.
    IP V6? No
    DHCP Server on LAN? Yes.
        DHCP range: 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254
```

Also Since I have one NIC I added a secondary bridge so I have 2 network cards for my pfSense vm. Here is the interfaces file content for proxmox network:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    bridge_ports enp6s0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    bridge_ports enp6s0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

vmbr0 is used for WAN and vmbr1 is used for LAN.

I also added 2 firewall rules in pfsense. One in Wan and the other in LAN:

```
Action: Pass
Interface: WAN
Address Family: IPv4
Protocol: Any
Source: 192.168.1.0/24
Destination: Any
Description: Allow LAN to Internet

Action: Pass
Interface: LAN
Address Family: IPv4
Protocol: Any
Source: 192.168.1.0/24
Destination: Any
Description: Allow LAN to WAN
```

Still can not ping Internet addresses (like 8.8.8.8).

I also noticed when I use Ping Host feature of pfSense, I can only ping LAN addresses and in **192.168.0.0/24** network I can only ping the address of pfSense which is 192.168.0.55. If I try to ping the dsl router IP which is 192.168.0.1 I get this message:

> Ping: sendto: Host is down.

Also Can not ping Internet addresses like 8.8.8.8 from there.
I also attached screenshots of the pfSense vm network adapter settings in proxmox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRlYk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnBdj.png